# Overlapping branches in git

Tags: git, branch, git-submodules

I have a git repository that has a number branches (eg branch1, branch2). One of those branches contains a submodule (eg submodule1).

Example directly structure for branch1:

```
$ ls
subdir1/
subdir2/
file1.txt
file2.txt
```

Example directly structure for branch2 (contains submodule):

```
$ ls
submodule1/
file1.txt
```

When I swich from branch2 to branch1 (`$ git checkout branch1`), the submodule from branch2 appears in branch1:

```
$ ls
subdir1/
subdir2/
submodule1/
file1.txt
file2.txt
```

How is this happening and why is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Submodules exist on the project level, they are not (necessarily) files unto themselves. Submodules themselves are defined in a file at the root directory of your git project, `.gitmodules`. This file outlines the local path and remote URL for the repository.

Conceptually, therefore, submodules do not exist "in" a branch, they are simply part of the repository itself. You also have not "checked in" the submodules files themselves at any point, so git isn't actually managing them in any way. It's actually "ignoring" them to an extent, and when you switch branches, it merely "steps around" these files, much like new files which are uncommitted and not under version control yet.